pyinstaller error, making .exe file with web crawler (FileNotFoundError : [Errno 2])
I'm a bit newbie of Python and also Progamming.
and this is my attempt to make my first Program.
Any kind of help or advice will be big help.
what I want :
making a .exe file that's working. I'm making web-crawler.
it's download.exe
I have 2 .py file.

main_final.py (contains codes to web-crawl)
download.py (contains GUI made from tkinter)

download.py
has 'import main_final.py' code
Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "main_final.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "user_agent\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "user_agent\base.py", line 45, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "user_agent\device.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "user_agent\device.py", line 10, in load_json_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\sa031\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI125882\\user_agent\\data/smartphone_dev_id.json'
[17784] Failed to execute script 'download' due to unhandled exception!


Error message from cmd
.exe file shows the above message and turns off.
what I tried

googled
and try to check the error point in the code below
tried to check if libraries I had imported get in properly.(not so sure, should I put everything into this hiddenimports=[] ? )
pyinstaller --onefile filename.py / same problem.


# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['download.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='download',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='download',
)



suspicious point
since I'm doing web -crawling, I got blocked from the site.
so I used 'user_agent'

from ipypb import ipb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from user_agent import generate_user_agent

import requests
import urllib.parse
import time
import random




def download(dir_to_save, url_to_download) :


    
    headers = {
    
    "User-Agent": generate_user_agent(os='win',device_type='desktop')
    # "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15"

    }

so I thought because it's getting some random user-Agent, something is wrong.
I tried to change "User-Agent" in headers to the specific one, which is below the generate_user_agent, and re- pyinstaller but still doesn't work.

I found that there is '/' '\' fusion in error message '2\\user_agent\\data/smartphone_dev_id.json' between \\data/smartphone_dev nothing is intended, and still the codes works well on my window labtop what I can I do to solve it?



as I also comment out the import part of user_agent it works, but I need user_agent to getting blocked


from ipypb import ipb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from user_agent import generate_user_agent

import requests
import urllib.parse
import time
import random




def download(dir_to_save, url_to_download) :


    
    headers = {
    
    # "User-Agent": generate_user_agent(os='win',device_type='desktop')
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15"

    }



I found that there is '/' '' fusion in error message
'2\user_agent\data/smartphone_dev_id.json'
between \data/smartphone_dev
nothing is intended, and still the codes works well on my window labtop
what I can I do to solve it?

get path from error and check if you have this file in this folder. PyInstaller creates self-extracting ZIP file which creates temporary folder _MEI125882 to extract code (and later it delete this folder) and you may have to manually add your user_agent\\data/smartphone_dev_id.json to configuration file spec when you run pyinstaller.

Using Spec Files — PyInstaller 6.6.0 documentation
